# How to create a regex excluding a Character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to create a regex, that matches only symbols (no letters, no digits) and that ignores dots and new lines.

I'm failry new to regexes an strugling. `\D\W` should work letter and digit wise but I can't find out how to NOT match something else. I'm using the re module in python 3.11. (Yes I'm trying to do advent of code day 3)

Comment: `\D\W` matches 2 characters, the first being not a digit and the second being not a word character. For  no letters a-zA-Z no digits no dots and no newlines use a character class `[^a-zA-Z\d.\n]`

Comment: I do not believe Python defines a "symbol", in which case saying you wish to match "only symbols" is meaningless. Moreover, characters are to be matched or not matched. Saying that some are to be "ignored" is not clear. The regex in the selected answer does not match spaces or tabs, but you say nothing about that. You simply need to enumerate the characters that are to be matched or the characters that are not to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern below.

### Pattern

```
[^\w\n\s.]
```

This blocks all word characters (`\w`), new lines (`\n`), and dots (`.`).
The caret `^` is used to negate the patterns inside the square brackets

### Test

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[^\w\n\s.]')
result = pattern.findall("Test me")

print(result)
```

It will output an empty list `[]`.